# Дубли в запросе после GroupBy

Tags: база-данных, postgresql, group-by

есть вот такой запрос:

```
SELECT "product".* FROM "product"
  LEFT JOIN "product_category" ON "product"."product_id" = "product_category"."product_id"
  LEFT JOIN "category" ON "product_category"."category_id" = "category"."category_id"
  LEFT JOIN "product_variant" ON ("product"."product_id" = "product_variant"."product_id")
                                   AND ("product_variant"."stock" != 0)
  LEFT JOIN "product_image"
    ON "product_variant"."product_variant_id" = "product_image"."product_variant_id"
  LEFT JOIN "brand" ON "product"."brand_id" = "brand"."brand_id"
  LEFT JOIN "product_option" ON "product"."product_id" = "product_option"."product_id"
  LEFT JOIN "tax_option" ON "product_option"."option_id" = "tax_option"."tax_option_id"
WHERE "category"."category_id" IN (21, 22, 313, 315, 342)
GROUP BY "product"."product_id"
ORDER BY "product"."is_top" DESC, "product"."sort" LIMIT 15
```

В итоге, после такой скатерти с Left Join и группировки, БД возвращает вот такой кусок данных:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что я не учел, и делаю не так, что Group By на выходе выдаёт 2 строки, а не 1(как я почему то был уверен,что при любом раскладе должно юыло выдатся)

P.S СУБД - PostgreSQL

Comment: Какой кстати смысл в LEFT join при том что из этих таблиц на вывод не попадает ничего вообще загадка. Если таблица в запросе нужна для фильтрации в where то никакого LEFT быть не должно, он сбивает с толку не только читающего запрос, но и оптимизатор, что может в некоторых случаях приводить к тому что запрос будет выполняться несколько часов вместо нескольких секунд

Comment: @Mike Запрос не мой. Мне он предстал в таком виде, когда оказались вот такие дубли

Comment: Добавьте в начале DISTINCT. Т.е. запрос будет начинаться так ```SELECT DISTINCT "product".* FROM "product" ... ```

Comment: В общем тут что то не ясное. я обнаружил, что postgresql действительно позволяет указывать в group by только первичный ключ таблицы и при этом делать select tablle.*. Но вот смоделировать ситуацию мне не удалось, в тесте с 2мя таблицами, которые без group by размножают записи добавление group by оставляет действительно только одну строку. И собственно так и должно быть по стандартам (правда стандарты не позволяют делать group by только по PK). В общем это похоже на баг СУБД